# Log in to my Apple ID via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, apple-id

Lets assume I have some Mac machine without access to the UI - only Terminal.

Is there any possibility to log in to my Apple ID via Terminal?

I want to log in and it should be logged in after this.

Comment: Once you would be logged in, what would you do with that afterwards? What do you expect to be enabled once you've logged in?

Comment: I want for example install some apps from app store

Comment: Is there even a way to download content from the store once you are authenticated?

Comment: Maybe it would be worth to rewrite the question to focus on the goal here -> "How can I download/install from the App Store from Terminal"

Answer (score 0):

You can install [`mas`](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas) via `brew install mas`.

Enter the command `mas signin your_email@example.com` and press Enter. Then provide your Apple ID password when prompted, though note that the characters won't be visible as you type.

If successful, a message will appear. `mas` primarily manages programs from the Mac App Store.

Also, please, check out the [limitations of `mas`](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas#%EF%B8%8F-known-issues)

Comment: Might be worthing noting https://github.com/mas-cli/mas#%EF%B8%8F-known-issues though.